# Would our Billion 7800n router support symmetrical 4Mbit upload/download?

Tags: router

Our local telecommunications company claims our Billion 7800n router won't support our new office connection which is supposedly "symmetrical 4Mbit down/up".

Is this true?

Comment: What kind of "symmetrical 4mbit down/up" line are you getting? I assume since that's an ADSL router they are upgrading you to SHDSL which can use multiple copper pairs to achieve data rates higher than traditional ADSL. Chances are you are getting two or more copper lines that will feed into that router and that router only has 1 port... again just a guess as I don't have any info on the router or the new line they will putting in.

Comment: To be honest I dont have the specifics, I just wanted to check the sales guy wasnt just trying to sell us another router for more comission

Comment: In case anyone else arrives here. I can confirm that the 7800N supports up to 100Mbps connections. I'm currently using it on a 40/10 async FTTC connection. It has an EWAN port as well as an ADSL port. You would need the connection to be terminated as Ethernet so you would probably need some kind of terminating equipment. My ISP provides a "residential gateway" but that connection is very similar to a "Cable Modem". SDSL connections might be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Billion website [here](http://www.billion.com/product/wireless/BiPAC-7800N-11n-ADSL2-Broadband-Firewall-Router-Gigabit.html) for that particular router, as well as the linked user manual makes no mention of it supporting SDSL, so I would safely make the assumption that they are correct. According to the specification sheet it only supports ADSL/ADSL2+.

I would suggest you chat with your ISP in this case about which router to get, since [this](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sdsl+routers&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) brief Google search did not reveal a lot of options, and even fewer cheap options looking at the first 2 pages.

Comment: Thanks Diago, looking at the details for the router again I couldnt see any mention of SDSL and its safe to say if it supported it would mentioned it in the features or have some sort of logo on the box

Answer (score 1):

> "The BiPAC 7800(N) series is compliant with worldwide ADSL standards,
>   and supports download rates of up to 12/24Mbps using ADSL2/2+, 8Mbps
>   using ADSL and an upload rate of up to 1Mbps." (Billion Website)

If you are required to use any other protocol to ADSL or ADSL2+, you will require a new router. However as Kyle noted it is essential that you provide a more specific identification of the particular protocol that your new connection needs to support.